# Prevent anchor link to adding to the url in Django

Tags: html, django-views, django-templates

I have a project where I can list distributions. I have a homepage where I have the options to click on the lecture or lecturer. Now I want that when I am on the lecturers page that I can click on one anchor tag which redirects me to the target page. However the URL does only add the new slug. I will post the urls and templates. Hope you can help me, Thanks in advance.

urls.py

```
app_name='distribution'

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.Index.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',views.LecturerDistribution.as_view(),name='lecturer_distribution'),
    path('dersler/<slug:slug>/',views.LectureDistribution.as_view(),name='lecture_distribution'),
]
```

this my part in the lecture code template

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'distribution:lecture_distribution' slug=i.lecturer.slug%}">{{i.lecturer}}</a> | {{i.semester}}</p>
```

and here is my cbv for the lecture_distribution

```
class LectureDistribution(generic.DetailView):
    model=Lecture
    template_name='lecture.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lecture_distribution', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['distribution_'] = Distribution.objects.filter(lecture=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context
```

my url when I am clicking on the anchor tag is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dagilimlar/dersler/mehmet-cem-guclu/
```

But it should

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dagilimlar/mehmet-cem-guclu/
```

as you see the "dersler" field is there which should not it is only for the lectures.

Comment: Then you should give the two views a different name. RIght now both are applicable, and then it will normally take the latter. Exactly why is there a `path('dersler/<slug:slug>', ...) in the first place?

Comment: there are 2 different views with different names.

Comment: the path you mentioned is for the lecture view and the other for the lecturer

Comment: Then there is a typo in your template. It should be `{% url 'distribution:lecturer_distribution' slug=i.lecturer.slug%}` :)

Comment: Ah yes I see :) Sorry for that